# replace vector of characters using separate dataframe of different length

Tags: r, if-statement, gsub

There is a character vector (~35,000 rows) (col1) that I would like to recode/rename based on a separate dataframe (df1). They are all character vectors.

```
col1
C
B
M A
B
R R
C
R R
M A
B

df1:

V1   V2
B    blanket
C    toy
M A  blarg
R R  targe
```

The outcome would be

```
col1
toy
blanket
blarg
blanket
targe
toy
targe
blarg
blanket
```

What I am trying to do is say "if V1 = col1, replace with V1 = V2"
I tried to write that literally:

```
out<-if(col1==df$V1){replace(df$V1 == df$V2)}
```

which throws:

```
Warning message:
In if (testdat == schooldf$V1) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

And I tried to use gsub:

```
out<-gsub(df$V1, df$V2, col1)
```

which throws:

```
1: In gsub(schooldf$V1, schooldf$V2, testdat) :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In gsub(schooldf$V1, schooldf$V2, testdat) :
  argument 'replacement' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Clearly the issue is similar in both arguments I tried, but I'm not able to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning you are getting with your `replace` code comes from the fact that you used `if()` which is meant for flow control, not variable creation. It is only meant to take a logical value of length 1 (TRUE or FALSE). Also the syntax for `replace` is incorrect, see `?replace` or the last part of my answer below:

One idea is to do this with a `match` rather than `replace`. `replace` only does one condition at a time

```
col2 <- df1$V2[match(col1, df1$V1)]
col2
#[1] "toy"     "blanket" "blarg"   "blanket" "targe"   "toy"     "targe"   "blarg"   "blanket"
```

The result is a character vector since you say that's what `col1` is in your question. If `col1` is a `data.frame` you can still use the same method.

And if you have some potential non-matches you could use `replace` to make sure the original `col1` values remain:

```
replace(col2, is.na(col2), col1[which(is.na(col2))])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `merge`, assuming your `col` is in `df`

`merge(df1, df, by.x = "v1", by.y = "col", all.y=T)`